# Deploying webservice on remote machine

Tags: java, web-services, networking, static-ip-address

This might sound a very basic question for the N/W gurus so please try to help me here.

I have developed a simple Webservice in Java and deployed it on a local machine using Eclipse/Ant. The path looks like this -

http://localhost:8284/myws?wsdl

Now, I have provided a static IP for the local machine say XX.XX.XXX.XX and I can ping it from any remote machine over internet.

In my Java program, I have provided endpoint name as -

"http://localhost:8284/myws" and it works fine on local machine and opens the wsdl just fine in a browser.

Now, I want to deploy this webservice in a way that, I can access it remotely using my static IP i.e XX.XX.XXX.XX

Problem 1:

When I try to assign the endpoint as 
"http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8284/myws" my Java program gives error saying

Server Runtime Error: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind

Problem 2:

If I deploy it as "http://localhost:8284/myws", I am not able to access it over internet using URL like http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:8284/myws?wsdl.

Things I have did so far - -

a. Turned off the firewall
b. Created 2 rules inbound/outbound with port 8284 allowed.

My question is, will I need a router to do a port-forwarding thing? Or will I need an IIS to deploy it?

I really want to ignore both of them. If there is any simple way to do that please let me know. Am I missing something? I am able to ping the IP and can also connect through RDC.

Info -

Machine is on Windows 7.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: is that a public ip address that you are trying to bind to?

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved. I used http://0.0.0.0:8284/cal while binding and not localhost:8284/cal

Works like a gem now! Hope it helps someone.

Regards,
Bhushan.